# How to gracefully stop react-native run-ios?

Tags: ios, react-native

I see a lot of process is started when I run this command

`npx react-native run-ios`

But I don't see any command like `stop-ios`. Looks like I have to kill all the process manually like Simulator, Metro bundler, etc.

I'm using Mac. Is there any alternative for this ? For both iOS and Android

Answer (score 6):

You only need to press "CMD + C" or "CTRL + C" or exit the terminal, or use the command below.

`killall node`

If on Mac OS it is the best way.